# h:commandButtoon and f:ajax does not render a h:dataTable if no action property is provided

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have the followig form with a dataTable and a edit section with input fields to manipulate the table data. I want to refresh the datatable after a the commandButton was clicked:

```
<f:ajax>
<h:panelGroup id="timesheet_panel">
    <h:dataTable id="datatable"
            value="#{timesheetController.myTimeSheet}" var="child">
    ......
        <h:column>
        <!-- update editor panel data -->
        <h:commandLink
            action="#{timesheetController.load(child.item['$uniqueid'])}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.edit}" />
            <f:ajax
                render=":#{component.parent.parent.parent.parent.clientId}:editorpanel" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    <!-- Editor  -->
    <h:panelGroup id="editor">
        <h:inputText value="#{timesheetController.workitem.item['_category']}" />

        <h:commandButton action="/mypage"
                    actionListener="#{timesheetController.process('10')}"
            value="Update Tabledata">
            <f:ajax render="datatable" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
</f:ajax>
```

Note: I have a h:column with a h:commandLink to update the data shown in the editor panel below the table.

The question is: why is it necessary to provide the action property for the commandButton in the editor panel? If I did not provide the action property the f:ajax render="datatable" will not refresh the datatable. 
So it seems to me that only a actionListener can be used here to update backend data. A action method will only work if the result of the action is equal to the current page.
Can anybody explain this behavior? 
I am working on GlassFish 3.1.2

Comment: After I added the 'action' property to my 3rd button 'Test3 Listener' it seems to work. But why is the action property necessary after all?

Comment: are you sure that `actionListener="#{timesheetController.process('10')}"` worked for you ? passing parameter to `actionListener` method is wrong... you can pass parameter to `action` method

Comment: also , instead of using `<f:setPropertyActionListener `  pass arguments to your `action` method directly...

Comment: Why would you wrap all that code into a `<f:ajax>`?

Comment: I tested different variants of commandButtons. It seems to me that a action to the same page is obligatory for a commandButton with a f:ajax event. If I did not provide the action render did not work.

Comment: I asked why you have `<f:ajax> JSF components and code </f:ajax>`.

Comment: If id did not wrap the section into a f:ajax tag the datatable will not be rerendered. I have now also updated my question.

Comment: Is there any thing in my example code shown above totally wrong? As I wrote I simplified this example. The question is: why is the action attribute in the h:commandButton mandatory to get the h:datatable rerendered?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the table you need to put your bean in **@ViewScoped** at least. Ortherwise, your beed will be recreated after values are set so you'll get to same point.

Comment: the backing bean is in @SessionScope. But the dataTable will not be rerendered after my action method was triggered.